# Can I partition the C# System.Threading.ThreadPool?

Tags: c#, threadpool

I love ThreadPool.  It makes my life better.  However, my love may have quietly turned into an abusive relationship that I need to escape from, so I need some advice from my SO brothers (and presumably sisters, although I haven't seen any actual evidence of that yet).

My basic problem is that I have several different libraries that are all using the threadpool in an uncoordinated way, and running out of threads is a possibility.  I was hoping there was some way I could partition the ThreadPool up so I could give a certain class 1 thread, another 20 threads, another 5 threads, and so on.

I know I could write my own ThreadPool implementation.  I don't want to do that, because I'm lazy.  So, is there a simple solution already out there?

Currently I'm constrained to using the 3.5 CLR.  I know a lot of this stuff becomes easier in 4.0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nope, unfortunately not. It's one of my bugbears with the .NET thread pool as well. Even in .NET 4 with Parallel Extensions, it's generally based on a single system thread pool - you'd have to do some work to create your own individual thread pools (and feed that into tasks as a task scheduler, or something similar).

I suspect MS has researched this and found that *most* customers are find with a single thread pool - but I agree it would be nice to have a bit more flexibility here...

Comment: One J.Skeet has written a configurable thread-pool in [MiscUtils](http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/miscutil/), a utility library.

Comment: @Ani: Yes, but that's very old code, badly tested, and almost certainly with various flaws. I'm not removing it from MiscUtil, but I'm not going to promote it anywhere. Hopefully it's been implemented better elsewhere :)

Comment: Found SmartThreadPool a few minutes after asking this question.  Looks like my best bet would be to start using that.  I especially like that exceptions are returned back to the original caller - that feature alone is probably enough to make it preferable to System.Threading.ThreadPool.

Answer (score 0):

Don't rewrite your own ThreadPool.

Why don't you just use an [Adapter Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adapter_pattern) to actually implement just the logic you need?

Comment: How does the adapter pattern help here?

Comment: Maybe not adapter pattern then... The idea is your adapter will forward all calls to the thread pool after filtering by caller class. Maybe a Brige Pattern?

Comment: Again, I can't see how that helps. It can't easily limit the threads per pool without basically writing a pool yourself.

Comment: @Jon, why not? I was thinking a semaphore per pool before accessing the .NET Thread Pool itself...

Comment: So you'd be keeping track of the number of tasks still running "in" each thread pool (and queuing ones for later submission), but without actually knowing whether they'd been allocated a thread yet in the "real" thread pool... it sounds very much like it has the downsides of writing your own threadpool but without some of the advantages.

Answer (score 0):

My understanding based on MSDN articles is that the thread pool is meant for short lived threads. The whole idea of the thread pool is creating new kernel threads has lots of overhead, so create one kernel thread and let that thread do work on one thing, then move to the next.

If you have long running threads in your thread pool, you need to move those to regular threads.

If you're "running out" of threads, then they're running too long.

Comment: I abuse the threadpool, and make no bones about it.  That being said, it is perfectly possible for a high-concurrency application (think web server) to use the threadpool appropriately and still run out.